# Yii php script is working but cronjob on linux server is not working

Tags: php, linux, yii, cron

I have set cron job for every minute like :

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php path/to/cron.php checkcron
```

When I run it using SSH console, its work fine :

```
php cron.php checkcron
```

but it is not working automatically by server.

Comment: What happens, do you see messages in the error log, etc.?

Comment: verify your directory for php. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your php path is correct, If it's not working, Then You can simply create a file in your project and use that file to trigger the cron file.

So the file looks like this

```
//file name:cron-trigger.php
        <?php

        exec("php cron.php > data.log &");

        ?>
```

Assume set a url : http://example.com/cron-trigger.php
and call this in your cron tab

```
wget -q -O cron_exec.html http://example.com/cron-trigger.php
```

Comment: Creating a web-accessible cronjob trigger script is a very bad idea.

Comment: I know it's not a good practice, IAlso he can set permission to access the link from a specific IP(server) if some security issue was their.

Comment: i have found this error in error log  Could not open input file: /path/to/cron.php

Comment: You need to give the exact full path of where your cron file is occurred.

For eg: /var/home/user/cron.php